# How to do edit of a table in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a functional component in react js that allows you to do both insertion and modification via the call with axios, insertion works, but modification doesn't and I don't understand why, every time I click the button to modify.
Forgive me for my English

Testing the functional component through the routing and the link in the various buttons, I noticed that the pages work, you can see everything both for the insertion and for the modification with the exact title and all the inputs to insert the data, but unlike of the insertion where as soon as I click the button to create the record it works, in the modification as soon as I click the button, in the console it fills with errors and does not modify the record

My main table:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Stack } from "@mui/material";
import Icon from '@mdi/react';
import { mdiPlusCircle } from '@mdi/js';
import { mdiPencil } from '@mdi/js';
import { mdiDelete } from '@mdi/js';

class PersonaleTabella extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            elenco: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8091/services/personale/list")
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                const responsePersonale = response.data;

                this.setState({ elenco: responsePersonale });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Errore durante il recupero dei dati:", error);
            });
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div className="cont">
                <h1>Componente della classe</h1>


                <TableContainer component={Paper} className="table-container">
                    <Table>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>

                                <TableCell><Link to="inserimento" state={{id:"",nome:"", cognome:"", indirizzo:"",cap:"",paese:""}}><Button variant="contained" color="success"><Icon path={mdiPlusCircle} size={1} /></Button></Link></TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Nome</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Cognome</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Indirizzo</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Cap</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Paese</TableCell>
                                <TableCell></TableCell>

                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {this.state.elenco.map(personale => (
                                <TableRow key={personale.id}>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                                            <Link to="modifica" state={{id:"",nome:"", cognome:"", indirizzo:"",cap:"",paese:""}}>
                                                <Button variant="contained"><Icon path={mdiPencil} size={1} /></Button>
                                            </Link>

                                            <Button variant="contained" color="error"><Icon path={mdiDelete} size={1} /></Button>

                                        </Stack>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{personale.nome}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{personale.cognome}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{personale.indirizzo}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{personale.cap}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{personale.paese}</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
            </div >
        )
    }
}

export default PersonaleTabella;
```

Functional component for editing and inserting:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { Box, Button, TextField, Paper } from '@mui/material';
import Icon from "@mdi/react";
import { mdiHomeCircle } from "@mdi/js";

function PersonaleGestione() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const isModifica = location.pathname.endsWith("modifica");
  console.log(location.state);
  
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(location.state);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const { nome, cognome, indirizzo, cap, paese } = formData;



    if (!nome || !cognome || !indirizzo || !cap || !paese) {
      console.error("Per favore, compila tutti i campi obbligatori.");
      return;
    }
    
    if (isModifica) {
      axios.put("http://localhost:8091/services/personale/aggiornamento/", formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log("Personale aziendale modificato con successo!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Errore durante l'aggiornamento dei dati:", error);
        });
    } else {
      axios.post("http://localhost:8091/services/personale/inserimento", formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log("Personale aziendale inserito con successo!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Errore durante l'inserimento dei dati:", error);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="cont">
      <Paper elevation={3} style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <h1>{isModifica ? "Modifica" : "Inserimento"} del Personale</h1>
        <Box mb={2}>
          <Link to="/personale">
            <Button variant="contained"><Icon path={mdiHomeCircle} size={1} /></Button>
          </Link>
        </Box>
        <Box mb={2}>
          <TextField
            label="Nome"
            name="nome"
            value={formData.nome}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box mb={2}>
          <TextField
            label="Cognome"
            name="cognome"
            value={formData.cognome}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box mb={2}>
          <TextField
            label="Indirizzo"
            name="indirizzo"
            value={formData.indirizzo}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box mb={2}>
          <TextField
            label="Cap"
            name="cap"
            value={formData.cap}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box mb={2}>
          <TextField
            label="Paese"
            name="paese"
            value={formData.paese}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Box>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          {isModifica ? "Modifica" : "Inserisci"}
        </Button>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PersonaleGestione;
```

Forgive me if there is something written in my language, if it bothers me I will change it to english